# Any element in list is an integer

Tags: python, list

I have a list, which potentially contains a list (and this subsequently can also can be made up of lists, ad infinitum). Is there a way to test if any element at the 'bottom' of these lists has an integer? The list will always have numbers (floats or ints) eventually.

As I don't know the number of nested lists of it beforehand, the only way I can think of doing so would be something like,

```
x = [[[[5]]]]
if (len(str(x)) != len(str(x).replace('.','')) or ('int' not in str(x)):
    int_in_list = False
```

Is there a more logical way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using something like [`collapse()` from the more-itertools library](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.collapse), which will recursively descend into lists and other iterable types and yield the fundamental non-iterable elements. You can then just check whether any of the elements yielded by `collapse()` is an integer.

```
any(isinstance(x, int) for x in collapse(...))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here ya go:

```
numlist = [[[[[1]]]]]

def recursive_flatten(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            yield from recursive_flatten(item)
        yield item

if any(isinstance(item, int) for item in recursive_flatten(numlist)):
    # Horray
    pass
```